# Проблема отображения изображения иконки BrowserWindow (Electron.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, electron

Я загрузил png-изображение значка с белым фоном, и оно отлично отобразилось, затем я загрузил изображение того же размера с прозрачным фоном, но вместо него - стандартный значок Linux.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу обьяснить в чём может быть проблема и как её решить

Comment: win.setIcon(icon) - так не пробовали?

Comment: @Виктор только что попробовал, ничего не дало, результат аналогичен , первому и второму скриншоту в зависимости от изображения

Comment: Возможно с картинками что-то. c logo2. Размер WxH может слишком большой или ещё что

Comment: @Виктор у меня тоже были мысли подобного рода, я уменьшал размер изображения с прозрачным фоном так как были подозрения что дело в размерах изображений , это не дало результат как таковой, ну а в формате различий то и нет - .png

Comment: Здесь инфа интересная - https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/native-image Ещё, расширение png - ни о чём не говорит

Comment: @Виктор читал эту статью и ничего полезного не увидел, если у вас есть предложения касательно статьи - пишите . Ну по моему мнению расширение таки имеет определённое значение в вопросах поддержки технологией потому и упомянул.